# Upgrading my T61 with an SSD and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd, thinkpad

I am going to upgrade my trusty Thinkpad with a shiny new OS (Windows 7) and SSD (80GB Intel X25, now under €200).

I was wondering whether this will be as easy as I hope: in particular, is it enough to install the OS onto the fresh drive and then download and install the Windows 7 drivers from Lenovo? Or will I end up with problems (e.g. hotkeys not working, losing the Thinkvantage suite, ...) ?

Anyone with experience here? I can't be the first one to do this.

Comment: No first-hand experience, but our company just upgraded a lot of Lenovos (T61s too) to Windows 7 by doing a clean install and updating the drivers. It really can't be that hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed Windows 7 a few times, dead easy. once you have installed Windows 7, hop onto the Lenovo Website and install the thinkvantage system update program. once it is installed run an update and it will install all of the other think vantage programs for you.

It can take a while but it is really easy as it is all done for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my sixth ThinkPad (an X200s), which I upgraded to Windows 7 Enterprise with no problems at all.  Install the latest ThinkVantage drivers and use System Update 4 afterwards, to get all the latest versions of the tools.

Remember not to install the ThinkVantage Active Protection System software, as you will not be needing it!

[This is the page you need.](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/migr-67853.html)  Enter the model number of your T61 on the left hand side.  You'll find it on the black sticker at the bottom of the laptop.

It's a good idea to [install this first](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-73684), before even using Windows Update.